# What does wq_busy=1 indicate in a failure to suspend?

Tags: suspend, log, dmesg

After upgrade to 15.10, my laptop no longer suspends.  `dmesg` says

```
[…] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[…] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[…] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[…] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... 
[…] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.008 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1):
```

That seems to blame `wq_busy` for being true, but I'm not having luck finding out why that might be the case or how I might fix it.  (Internet searches seems to always pull up the more popular case where a task refuses to freeze.)  What does `wq_busy=1` indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wq_busy` is apparently the kernel's variable name for the busy
flag on a workqueue.  Why it was stuck at true for some workqueue
on my machine is unclear, because the problem went away while I
was trying to diagnose it.  In case it's useful for someone in
the future, I had done the following:

1. Repeatedly until all applications were closed:

   1. Close an application.
   2. Attempt, unsuccessfully, to suspend.
2. Disable networking.
3. Attempt, unsuccessfully, to suspend.
4. Reboot (intending to get a clean process list; I was going to progressively disable things in hopes that a non-critical process was the culprit).
5. Attempt, unexpectedly successfully, to suspend.
6. Re-enable networking.
7. Attempt, again successfully, to suspend.

So, strictly based on observations, and not with any understanding of
the problem, I would guess that the following is a workaround or fix:

1. Disable networking.
2. Reboot.
3. Re-enable networking.

Comment: i can confirm that disabling networking with `nmcli netwoking off` and rebooting (without re-enabling) fixes the issue. I'm going to see if the issue comes back when I re-enable netwokring.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. `wq_busy` was 1. I suspected that it had started to happen after 18.10 upgrade.

I did some research and found a post about looking for hardware-specific solutions especially for laptops, and another post about `cdemu`.

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-952364-start-0.html

In my case, removing `gcdemu`, `cdemu-client`, `cdemu-daemon`, and then autoremove `vhba-dkms` and `libmirage11` made my hibernation working again.

Comment: In my case, stopping all cdemu processes and `modprobe -r`ing the vhba kernel module fixed the issue. (Removing the vhba module may have been overkill i'm not sure)

Comment: Thank you so much! I lost so many hours trying to make hibernation work on my laptop. And gcdemu was the issue! I uninstalled it and it's working perfectly now (Kubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 1):

I enabled hibernation some month ago in my Ubuntu system, now 20.04, but now as in the past I had some issue.
So in this last event I found this in "dmsg" during hibernation procedure:

```
 Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1)...
```

I solved with increasing the freezing timeout from 20 sec to 30 sec:

```
echo 30000 > /sys/power/pm_freeze_timeout
```

and made I it permanent with **sysfsutils** and after writing

```
power/pm_freeze_timeout = 30000
```

in a file in the **/etc/sysfs.d** directory